# dbt jinja "elif" functionality?

Tags: if-statement, jinja2, dbt

According to the jinja documentation, a tag exists for the `else if` case within an `if` and `else` flow: [Jinja Control Strucutures/IF](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if)

Looking for a way to do this within a dbt macro something like:

`my_macro.sql`

```
-- macros/my_macro.sql
{% macro my_macro() %}
  {% if target.name == 'default' %}
      select 'A' as my_letter;
  {% elif target.name == 'dev' %}
      select 'B' as my_letter;
  {% elif target.name == 'qa' %}
      select 'C' as my_letter;
  {% elif target.name == 'prod' %}
      select 'D' as my_letter;
  {% else %}
     select 1; -- hooks will error if they don't have valid SQL in them, this handles that!
  {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

If the `elif` tag or equivalent is unavailable, what are my options?
Something like the below only?

```
-- macros/my_macro.sql
{% macro my_macro() %}
  
  {% if target.name == 'default' %}
    select 'A' as my_letter;
  {% else %}
    select 1;
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if target.name == 'dev' %}
    select 'B' as my_letter;
  {% else %}
    select 1;
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if target.name == 'qa' %}
    select 'C' as my_letter;
  {% else %}
    select 1;
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if target.name == 'prod' %}
    select 'D' as my_letter;
  {% else %}
    select 1;
  {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disregard the question above - it was an indentation issue.

`{% elif %}` tags work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `elif` in dbt jinja without issue. is there a reason you don't have this available?